# Bearer Token by custom field in Header

Tags: c#, .net, header, authorization, token

My endpoint uses a token to authorize the execution but the header "Authorization" field is used for the gateway token.
I'd like to set a different header key to pass and read the token in my endpoints and avoid conflicts.

This is my controller code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ApiVersion("1.0")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorMessageDto), 500)]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(NavMenuItemReturnDto), 201)]
        public IActionResult CreateNavMenuItem(NavMenuItemUpdateCreateDto newNavMenuItem)
        {
            try
            {
                return StatusCode(201, _navMenuItemsBL.CreateNewNavMenuItem(newNavMenuItem).Result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, new ErrorMessageDto { Error = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

This is my startup code:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("JwtAuthority").Get<string>();

                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        RequireExpirationTime = false,
                        ValidateLifetime = false,
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                    };
                });
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Could you achieve what you are after with adding Multiple Authentication Schemas?

An Example is below:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Audience = "https://localhost:5000/";
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000/identity/";
        })
        .AddJwtBearer("AzureAD", options =>
        {
            options.Audience = "https://localhost:5000/";
            options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/eb971100-6f99-4bdc-8611-1bc8edd7f436/";
        });
}
```

> Only one JWT bearer authentication is registered with the default
> authentication scheme JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme.
> Additional authentication has to be registered with a unique
> authentication scheme.
>
> The next step is to update the default authorization policy to accept
> both authentication schemes. For example:

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
                JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                "AzureAD");
            defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = 
                defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
        });
```

> As the default authorization policy is overridden, it's possible to
> use the [Authorize] attribute in controllers. The controller then
> accepts requests with JWT issued by the first or second issuer.

Now you have the default, and AzureAD

Comment: The gateway is between the client (consumer) and my endpoint. The gateway is like a proxy service and the client must pass gateway authentication and authorization before and then pass the endpoint authentication and authorization in the same call. If I understand what you shared with me I don't think it can resolve my problem. Thanks.